# Converting PDF to PNG imagemagick vs GIMP

Tags: image, pdf, png, gimp

I'm trying to batch convert PDF's to PNG's. Previously, this was always done manually through GIMP by importing a PDF, then converting it to PNG.

With the script that I wrote, this should all be done automatically. But for some reason, the image quality I get from using

`convert \
 -density 300 \
 -adaptive-resize 2048 \
 -define png:compression-level=9  \
 "File1"
 "File2"`

Doesn't have the same "quality" compared to doing it via GIMP. See the image below for the difference in image quality.

In GIMP, I don't change much to the image. When I import the PDF, I change the resolution to 2048 pixels. When I convert and export it to PNG, I use all the default values GIMP offers, nothing fancy.

Changing the density to a higher or lower value doesn't do anything to the image. Also changing adaptive-resizing to normal resizing doesn't do much.

In the example image, both pictures are 2048 pixels wide. As you can see the lower image has a lot thicker/blurrier lines.

Example image comparison:

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the -density to 600 or 1200 and try again. Otherwise, post your original PDF

Comment: Tried to increase and decrease the density, the image got sharper. But the lines got thinner and the image overall got less and less opaque.
Although I have the image getting closer and closer to the GIMP one. It's still not the same. If in the original pdf there is a black line that is exactly one pixel, the convert script will add some "blur" and in the PNG file from the script it gets a greyish line one pixel above the line and below it.

Comment: Post your PDF file. Also note that Imagemagick relies upon Ghostscript to process PDF files. Is your Ghostscript up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a way around my problem. 
Increasing the PPI kind of helped but still not as much as I would have liked it to. 
Eventually I added this:

```
-channel A -fx "p*(p>0.2?22:0)"
```

Just some simple piece of code I found somewhere around here. It checks for the Alpha levels in the picture and if it's below a certain threshold it will just remove or "make the pixel" transparent. If it's over the threshold it will just boost the pixel to maximum visibility. Combined with the high PPI I dont get any "half pixels" anymore.